# TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not “float”) to tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to solve Runge-Kutta with Python. My function works well, but I need to fix it and became it more flexible with an args tuple. In the future, I'll need a args tuple to apply in a complex ODE. I tryed this way:

```
import numpy as np

h = 0.2  #space between t

#conditions
numeroEquacoes = 2   #number of equations   
numeroPassos = 10    #step time
t = np.zeros((numeroPassos))  
r = np.zeros((numeroPassos, numeroEquacoes))

#initial conditions
r[0] = np.array([1.0, 0.0]) #omega e y
t[0] = 0.0


def fun(r, t, k):
return np.array([r[1], k * r[0]])   #this is my ODE

def rk4(funcao, varIndep, varDep, esp, numeroPassos, args = ()):
    for i in range(1, numeroPassos):
         k1 = funcao(* ((varIndep[i-1], varDep[i-1]) + args) )
         k2 = funcao(* (varIndep[i-1] + (esp*0.5), varDep[i-1] + 
         ((esp* k1)*0.5) + args) )
         k3 = funcao(* (varIndep[i-1] + (esp*0.5), varDep[i-1] + ((esp 
         * k2)*0.5) + args) )
         k4 = funcao(* (varIndep[i-1] + esp, varDep[i-1] + (esp * k3) 
         + args) )
         varIndep[i] = varIndep[i-1] + esp
         varDep[i] = varDep[i-1] + ((esp/6)*(k1 + (2 * k2) + (2 * k3+ 
         k4))
    return varDep   #returns array r 

#testing my function
a = rk4(fun, t, r, h, numeroPassos, args=(2.0))
print (a)
```

I already have t, r, h and numeroPassos values. My args is k = 2.0. When this code is executed, the answer is:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "float") to tuple
```

When I use args = (2.0, ) on this test, it returns a new error message:

```
IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

How to fix it?

Comment: `args=(2.0)` is not a tuple, it's a float expression. Do this: `args=(2.0,)` instead.

Comment: I done it: args = (2.0, ), but it didn't work. The answer was: IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.

Comment: But now you are getting a different error message. Your code had several errors. It now has one less. Edit your question to include the *new* error message, the *full stack trace*, and at least *some information* about `t`, `r` and `h`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has many errors. 
Some remarks first: in your definition of "fun"

```
def fun(r, t, k):
    return np.array([r[1], k * r[0]])   #this is my ODE
```

You do not use `t` at all. Putting this aside, in rk4 you are using the following line:

```
k1 = funcao(* ((varIndep[i-1], varDep[i-1]) + args) )
```

It is clear with the list unpacking that you use that the function "fun" parameters will be:`r=varIndep[i-1] (**)` and `t=varDep[i-1]`.
But from the parameters you pass in: `a = rk4(fun, t, r, h, numeroPassos, args=(2.0,))` we see that `varIndep is np.zeros((numeroPassos)) (the global t you defined)` which is a 1 dimensional array and therefore `varIndep[i-1] is a float (not an array)` and so `(**) r is a float`. When you call "fun" the index error will come from the fact that r is not an array and `r[1]` doesn't make sense.